# How to check if condition in django template part

Tags: django-templates

I want add simple css class in the template first round of loop when for loop runs. {{forloop.counter}} shows count of for loops each time. so I want to do something like this  {% if forloop.counter==1 %} show {% endif %}. but it shows error as below:

Could not parse the remainder: '==1' from 'forloop.counter==1'

How to do it? any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting about the spaces around the equal signs:

```
{% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
```